# I do not understand part of the code example of hello world cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new  using  cocos2d-x and I'm reading HelloWorldScene.cpp code file, and so far I understood everything but the following lines of code:

```
void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
Director::getInstance()->end();
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
exit(0);
#endif
}
```

My question is the following: what does the variables CC_TARGET_PLATFORM, CC_PLATFORM_IOS do? , what does the line of cofigo Director::getInstance()->end() does -> end ();do?  and where  is  the funtion  menuCloseCallback being called?

here is the code:

```
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
//#include "MainmenuScene.h"

USING_NS_CC; 

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
// 'scene' is an autorelease object
auto scene = Scene::create();

// 'layer' is an autorelease object
auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

// add layer as a child to scene
scene->addChild(layer);

// return the scene
return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
//////////////////////////////
// 1. super init first
if ( !Layer::init() )
{
    return false;
}

Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

/////////////////////////////
// 2. add a menu item with "X" image, which is clicked to quit the program
//    you may modify it.

// add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                       "continuar.jpg",
                                       "continuar1.jpg",
                                          CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));

closeItem->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width - closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                            origin.y + closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));

// create menu, it's an autorelease object
auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
this->addChild(menu, 1);

/*////////////////////////////
// 3. add your codes below...

// add a label shows "Hello World"
// create and initialize a label

auto label = Label::createWithTTF("Hello World", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);

// position the label on the center of the screen
label->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2,
                        origin.y + visibleSize.height - label->getContentSize().height));

// add the label as a child to this layer
this->addChild(label, 1);

// add "HelloWorld" splash screen"
auto sprite = Sprite::create("HelloWorld.png");

// position the sprite on the center of the screen
sprite->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));

// add the sprite as a child to this layer
this->addChild(sprite, 0);*/

return true;
}


void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(Ref* pSender)
{
Director::getInstance()->end();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
exit(0);
#endif
}
```

Comment: `where is the funtion menuCloseCallback being called?`... you tell us! We can't see the rest of your code. Also, `CC_TARGET_PLATFORM` and `CC_PLATFORM_IOS` aren't normal variables, they're preprocessor variables for conditional compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                   "continuar.jpg",
                                   "continuar1.jpg",
                                      CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));
```

MenuItemImage has callbacks ( functions that call's on some event make):

- on button pressed but doesn't release finger from pushing - MenuItemImage show  continuar1.jpg, in other case it's show continuar.jpg.
- on button pressed (on finger push up after pressed it) - it call function HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback with parametr.

Answer (score 1):

The block of code

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
  exit(0);
#endif
```

checks to see if the target platform for compilation is iOS and if it is it adds in the exit(0);

The

Director::getInstance()->end();

ends the currently running app (closes - which is what the close menu item does)  This function is hooked up as call back in the menu item create.